# how to get params of generic constructor

Tags: typescript

I have a class `Collection` which accepts another class as param `personClass`.
I suppose method `add` should accepts params which includes in constructor of class `User`

```
class Person {
  constructor(public data: object) {
  }
}

type GetConstructorParams<T> = T extends {
  new (...params: infer Args): any
} ? Args : never

type GetConstructor<Instance> = new (...params: GetConstructorParams<Instance>) => Instance

class Collection<
  Instance extends Person
> {
  personClass: GetConstructor<Instance>
  items: Instance[] = []

  constructor(personClass: GetConstructor<Instance>) {
    this.personClass = personClass
  }

  add(...params: GetConstructorParams<Instance>) {
    const instance = new this.personClass(...params)
    this.items.push(
      instance
    )
  }
}

class User extends Person {
  data: {
     name: string
  }
  constructor(name: string) {
    super({name})
  }

  get name() {
    return this.data.name
  }
}

const collection = new Collection(User)

collection.add('123')
                ^^^ TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

Then I will try to make personClass as optional param. By default personClass should be equals `Person`

How to avoid error in this method `collection.add('123')`

Comment: [Please ask one main question per post.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741/511366).  I assume your main question is getting the constructor params right and that the part with making `personClass` optional is secondary and should be asked in a different post.  If so, then [this](https://tsplay.dev/WybLgw) is how I'd approach it.  If that works for you I can write up an answer; if not, then let me know what's missing.

Comment: I changed my question

Comment: So does [this code](https://tsplay.dev/WybLgw) meet your needs or not?

Comment: It works for me, thanks, but I still can't set personClass as optional param

Comment: Right, that should be a separate question post; you had two issues and you should only be asking about one of them.  You can do [this](https://tsplay.dev/wE56vw) but the explanation and issues surrounding it are out of scope for this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71162165/9758477

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class instance types in TypeScript do not hold a reference to their constructor type.  Consider the following class:

```
class Foo {
    a: number;
    constructor(a: number) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}

let f: Foo = new Foo(123);
```

The value `f` is annotated to be of type `Foo`.  But you should think of the type `Foo` as [an `interface`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) describing the shape of class instances, and not as meaning "was constructed by the `Foo` constructor".  Indeed, you can assign a value of the same shape to `f` without it being constructed by `Foo` at al:

```
f = { a: 456 }; // <-- also acceptable
```

If you look at [microsoft/TypeScript#3841](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841) you will see that even [the `constructor` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor) of a class instance is not strongly typed enough to determine anything about the actual constructor.

So, there's no way of looking at the type `Foo` and determining that the constructor named `Foo` has a constructor parameter of type `number`.  It's impossible to go from instance type to constructor type without losing information.
`GetConstructor<I>` will never work how you want.  There's no way to go from the type named `User` to the type named `typeof User`.

---

On the other hand, constructor types definitely know about the instances they construct.  So given the `User` constructor of type `typeof User`, you can get its instance type.  There's even [an `InstanceType<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) provided for you.

Furthermore, since all you care about is the instance type and the constructor parameter list, you can just make your `Collection` generic in the types of those directly, instead of caring about the constructor type itself.  Let's say that the constructor argument types is an arraylike type `A` and the instance type is a `Person`-like type `T`.  Then here's how `Collection` looks:

```
class Collection<A extends any[], T extends Person>{
    personClass: new (...args: A) => T;
    items: T[] = []

    constructor(personClass: new (...args: A) => T) {
        this.personClass = personClass
    }

    add(...params: A) {
        const instance = new this.personClass(...params)
        this.items.push(
            instance
        )
    }
}
```

That all compiles with no problem.  Then you can pass in `User` and see everything working as desired:

```
class User extends Person {
    data!: {
        name: string
    }
    constructor(name: string) {
        super({ name })
    }

    get name() {
        return this.data.name
    }
}

const collection = new Collection(User)
// const collection: Collection<[name: string], User>

collection.add('123'); // okay
```

The type of `collection` is `Collection<[name: string], User>`, corresponding to the fact that the `User` constructor takes a single `string` parameter and produces instances of type `User`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=49&ssc=22&pln=33&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PTALmgOwFcBbAIwFMAnAbnU2HjwgBcKDgn4KAKHfY8igEoUtTJiYALAJYQAdGGgBeLDTEBfVBpBkm0AGa4ESZXjIB3OIi4BGAEwBmQTT1KUWXABYArADZoaqmgAeiDoAB4AWgisEAgkMGBgMgAHJjASbVQs1FBIGAAFSji8ETF6RhY2Dm5kggypYGgAEzA03HgSACsydmE0dU0s3KhoAGF4EG12KQYwgEFoMgAPJjI8JpgwPABPAG0AXQAaaAAVRZW1jehCimKAPn7MZKKGUfAoXFMLLllfsAoAOYQXBzYSKO6nVSYKSrIjA04HVwHLJlBjMVjsThcZ63V7veFfaA-P6A+GgpQQk59URiaCSGSyHHFN55VxMvF5GkaGlgJpNYmM-5gOEg6m0uho3RSCpbJKuQn0uTsvAsqAC5JCuGCGliRWyGFkOGMggQCRcHXi6DS5iysgWjDagbc4YwACqEEo51W6wKLxKjwwLTSAEJcAHaXhhWRcOjpQCuTTyuiqljI0Ro9BY3gAWLLRACDiuMh8FH-I7MNyxACdCX01xc+KKDoCBQSnqg2BZGm7U6hpLoPRJj0mDMSiZzGMJlMRwwuO7KNqQgP+4Pp6PcOMh9NZrtuzGWHGjtB5xQ7n2tzO8PI+VwAOR2ey3wRAA)