# How to set class param default value in case this value is another class

Tags: typescript

[Code](https://tsplay.dev/NdjxYW)

I have class `Collection` which excepts `personClass` as param. How to set default value `Person` to `personClass` parameter?

```
class Person {
  constructor(public data: object) {
  }
}

class Collection<A extends unknown[], T extends Person>{
  personClass: new (...args: A) => T;
  items: T[] = []

  constructor(personClass: new (...args: A) => T = Person) {
              ^^^
              TS2322: Type 'typeof Person' is not assignable to type 'new (...args: A) => T'.   Types of construct signatures are incompatible.
    this.personClass = personClass
  }

  add(...params: A) {
    const person = new this.personClass(...params)
    this.items.push(person)
  }
}

class User extends Person {
  data: {
    name: string
  }
  constructor(name: string) {
    super({ name })
  }

  get name() {
    return this.data.name
  }
}

const collection = new Collection(User)
const anotherCollection = new Collection()

collection.add('1') // correct
collection.add(1) // show error as expected
collection.add({name: '123'}) // show error as expected

anotherCollection.add({
  name: '123',
  age: 1
}) // expected
anotherCollection.add('1') // expected error
```

Comment: The problem is that your current code allows `const yetAnotherCollection = new Collection<[name: string], User>();`, which would use the `Person` default value, but `Person` doesn't create `User` elements. I just wish I knew how to fix it... Fairly simple with a function, there *has* to be some equivalent way with a `class`...

Comment: The "good enough for most people" way around it is to just use a type assertion, since nobody will probably manually specify the type parameters.  Class constructors don't really let you do the same things you can do with a function, and even overloading the constructor won't behave the way you want (see [ms/TS#27594](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27594) and the issues linked within).  If you really worry about constructor callers being evil and you're okay giving up compiler-verified safety in the constructor impl, then you can do something like [this](//tsplay.dev/NrKZDm).

Comment: Your answer with [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NrKZDm) was removed by a mod because it was a link-only answer. You might want to post it with both the link *and* the code in the answer along with an explanation of what you did and how it works, for the benefit of others who may have the same problem. You can then accept that answer 48 hours after when you asked the question.